# How to keep blank lines around array in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, editor, settings

I use PhpStorm 2019.1.

I need to set up code style with new lines around arrays. Keep it always.

```
        $smt = $value;

        $ss = [
            'pr' => '4_',
            'r5d' => '4_n',
            'm4q' => '6_n',
            'p3e' => '3_n',
            'ctu' => '4_pn',
            'orv' => '4on',
            'eem' => '4on'
        ];

        $smth = [];
```

I was seeking of these settings in `Settings > Editor > Code style > PHP > Blank lines`. Apparently It has to be there. But I didn`t find it. There were only settings to insert new lines around functions and classes but not around arrays.

[image: Here is the image link]

Where is the settings which would help me with it? Or is this feature deprecated in this editor version?

Comment: I do not remember seeing such option for arrays. Array is just another variable just like `$smt = $value;` is ... why would I need a blank lines around it?..

Comment: I can`t explain it. Just my viewing of well formatting code. Thanks for the answer I never thought this way

Comment: Feel free to make a Feature Request ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI ... I just doubt that it will be implemented any time soon (for the reasons in my previous comment).